# "google.co.uk / referral" in Source/Medium of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Google Search results appear to be coming up in our Google Analytics as Referrals. I've tested using a Realtime report, and it's definitely proper search results, not traffic from a different Google Property.

When testing it, I tended to find that my initial click through from a Google search would be considered a referral, but returning and subsequently clicking through again could be an organic Session. However, I only did this a handful of times; it could be that there is no pattern.

There don't seem to be any strange Filters in place or anything.

Has anybody ever encountered this before?

UPDATE:

I have done a bit more digging, and noticed that the tracking implementation uses the urchinTracker(), which probably means it's not been updated in about 10 years. Not quite case closed, but it's a likely suspect.

Comment: If you found that to be the answer, you may add it as an answer to your own question.